# Does an NFS export with sec=krb5 *require* that the parent directory also be exported with sec=krb5?

Tags: linux, nfs, kerberos, autofs

I copied somebody's NFS server/client setup verbatim and am having trouble making sense of what's going on with it. This is the /etc/exports:

```
/export *(rw,fsid=0,crossmnt,insecure,async,no_subtree_check,sec=krb5p:krb5i:krb5)
/export/home *(rw,insecure,async,no_subtree_check,sec=krb5p:krb5i:krb5)
```

Client machines use autofs to mount user home directories on demand. Here's auto.home:

```
*       -fstype=nfs4,rw,soft,sec=krb5   192.168.0.2:/home/&
```

This works and works well. Still, exporting `/export` seems unnecessary so I commented that line out of the server config. Now automounting fails on the clients.

**Questions**

1. Why does `/export/home` require `/export` to also be exported?
2. Do the security options for `/export` and `/export/home` have to be the same?
3. Why does auto.home read `192.168.0.2:/home/&` instead of `192.168.0.2:/export/home/&`? It doesn't seem like that should work at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are using NFS version 4 (nfs4) which exports a single pseudo-filesystem rather than lots of separate filesystems.

This is specified on the NFS server in `/etc/exports` by `fsid=0`, and in your case is called /export (although it could be called anything). That is why you cannot remove that line or comment it out.

On the NFS client, this parent (in your case, `/export`) is seen as `/` (the root of the exported filesystem) which is why the automounter uses `/home`.

Comment: Thanks! I was unfamiliar with the "pseudo filesystem" concept. I see that I have to leave /export in the config. Now I would like to add some additional exports without sec=krb5. Any thoughts on my question #2?

Comment: They do not have to be the same. Whether they have to be a subset (remember it is a list of options) I am not sure. Try it and see.